# RPC on Umbrel via SSH - some bitcoin-cli commands don't return value

Tags: json-rpc, umbrel

I connected to my Umbrel full node from a terminal via SSH, and found that some of the bitcoin-cli commands don't return any value while others work fine. Some examples:

- **Working** - help, getinfo, getbestblockhash, getblock
- **Not working** - getbalance, listunspent, getnewaddress

When calling the "Not working" commands, there's no error message shown. I wonder what I'm missing? Here's what I use:

Umbrel v0.3.13

Windows PowerShell v1.0

RPC Client v0.21.1.0

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a wallet on your Bitcoin Core.

Note all your "not working" commands are wallet related and all "working" ones are blockchain related.

Comment: Thanks, you are right and now it works fine. Since my node is already running on Umbrel now, I will look up how to use it on RPC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RPC commands using bitcoin-cli bin for example

```
~/umbrel/bin/bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo
~/umbrel/bin/bitcoin-cli getblock "00000000c937983704a73af28acdec37b049d214adbda81d7e2a3dd146f6ed09"
```